# Switching to TEMPLATE style design from regular coding style

Tags: php, css, html

I have my script which will be sold to people. I have a standard design and every new people would want to have a design of his own choice. The problem is that I have not used any framework for programming (CodeIgnitor or Laravel). The script is totally coded in Core PHP with Bootstrap. Now the website has a mix of PHP coding and HTML coding (traditional way of coding). This is the only way of coding I know at this moment. I wanted to switch to a template based coding where I can keep the HTML files and PHP coding separate so that I can freely edit and change the design of the website just by editing the HTML and CSS files or by changing it on a different folder for test and then simply replacing the files by pasting the folder containing HTML and CSS files to it. Is there a way to do so? If yes, then please provide me a link to a good tutorial. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the way you think it is but You can achieve what you want by using a Framework. I recommend you to learn Laravel and the best way to learn it is watch the tutorials from https://laracasts.com.

You can change your design only by editing Views. But you need to get familiar with MVC principles first.

Answer (score 0):

without framework you may check template engine like https://twig.symfony.com/doc/templates.html (currently it getting popular) or https://www.smarty.net/ (old player but good one) or https://feulf.github.io/raintpl/ etc.